# C-FIND запрос возвращает пустой генератор

Tags: python, dicom

Всем привет!
Пишу первые запросы к PACS через `pydicom/pynetdicom`. Необходимо просто получить юиды исследования и серии. В качестве сервера запущен локально orthanc на стандартных портах.

```
def c_find_query():
"""
Выполняет C-FIND запрос и возвращает study_instance_uid, series_instance_uid
найденных исследований по параметрам датасета
"""

ae = AE()
ae.requested_contexts = QueryRetrievePresentationContexts
ae.supported_contexts = QueryRetrievePresentationContexts

ds = Dataset()
ds.QueryRetrieveLevel = 'SERIES'
ds.Modality = 'MG'

association = ae.associate('127.0.0.1', 4242)

if association.is_established:

    results = association.send_c_find(ds, query_model='1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.2.1.3')
    
    for (status, series) in results:
        if status.Status == 0xFF00:
            
            series_instance_uid = series.SeriesInstanceUID
            study_instance_uid = series.StudyInstanceUID
            association.release()
            return study_instance_uid, series_instance_uid

else:
    return "error"
```

`results` в итоге содержат пустой генератор, list(results) = [(, None)]

```
'Dataset' object has no attribute 'Status'
```

Кажется, я упускаю какой-то важный момент в понимании работы контекстов, запрашиваемых и поддерживаемых. Пакс не пустой. Направьте пожалуйста на путь истинный